# Difference between copy and \copy commands in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

To transfer data between a file and a table in postgresql there are two options

```
COPY my_table FROM '/Users/user/Downloads/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Or

```
\COPY my_table FROM '/Users/user/Downloads/test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

My question is what is the difference between the two and which one is faster?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `COPY` command is executed fully on server side - input/output is related to server side streams. But these streams can be redirected to client side - when you run `COPY` in a pre-configured environment. `\COPY` is this case.

`\COPY` is `psql`'s commands - it can be executed only from `psql` and it prepares internal environment for a possible read/write from client side streams, and it execute `COPY` commands.

So difference between `COPY` and `\COPY` is minimal. `\COPY` is `COPY` executed in different configuration for a possible read/write data from client. The performance should be same - `\COPY` can be a little bit slower due to network overhead (it is clear), but it should not be significant. In this case the communication protocol should be effective.

Comment: the `STDIN` pram to `COPY` makes it act pretty much like `\copy`, in case